Unable to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication - "The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context"
I am logged in to Windows machine and connected to another environment through GlobalProtect VPN to connect SQL Server. SQL Server is configured to allow only Windows authentication. But, Windows machine is in one domain and SQL Server is in another domain. And when I am trying to connect, it throws an error:

The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context.
(Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)

This is how I am trying to achieve this:

But it returning error as:

Here are the details:


I remove the  tag, since this isn't related to the SQL language.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

That image (again Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.) shows you are trying to use windows authentication with a username and password... That doesn't work. It's one or the other.

Don't think you can do such cross domain thing in ssms, so you'll have to figure out some other way to connect (via sql auth for example). Or you'll have to connect to a machine on sql server network and doing your work from there

You can, @siggemannen , if the 2 domains trust each other. I'm in an environment where we had 3 domains (now down the 2), and I use my Domain1\Thom account to access hosts and services (including previously SQL Servers) in Domain2 and Domain3.

Yeah, @ThomA, but here it looks like he's trying to use a different domain login, which i don't think one can do easily?

They could run SSMS as a different user,.@siggemannen . Again, provided the trust is there.

Which likely means there's no trust, @kls. If you want/need to use SQL Server with Windows Authentication you'll probably going to need to talk to your network admins. Otherwise use a SQL Login.

Speak to IT admins to set up trust between two domains, note that this has major security implications. Or use runas and ensure your machine has line of sight to Domain2's domain controller server. Note that the UserID and Password are ignored when using Integrated Security

To authenticate to a SQL Server in a different domain, use the runas /netonly technique.  This allows you to provide alternate credentials for network resources, and the credentials can be from another domain.
See, eg Using runas command to remotely logging into SQL Server
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/

What kind of app? Running on Windows?

Yes.  If you're self-hosting you can just use the runas /netonly.  Otherwise you can inject the credentials in the Windows credential store for the account under which the API App runs.  The second linked article has instructions for this.
